# How to quickly switch between XAML and Design mode in VisualStudio

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

When developing using any kind of `XAML` based technology,

is there a way to quickly switch between the XAML and `Design` mode in VisualStudio, using a `shortcut` or even a Command in the `Command Window` ?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by design mode? Xaml part is called as design mode.

Comment: i think you mean  Designer and Code Behind ? for that you can use F7 to go to XAML mode from code behind

Comment: @BalasubramaniM : check my update, no I don't mean Code Behind, I mean the XAML-only mode and the Design mode where you drag-and-drop controls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update 3 RC**; You can switch between XAML & Design View using **SHIFT + F7**;

[image: XAML to Design]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hopa, seems I need some updates, thx for the mention of `Update 3 RC`, mine is on Update 2, and those `F7` and `Shift+F7` aren't available, going right to `Extensions and Updates`, thx again !

Comment: @AymenDaoudi I checked it in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate Update 4, Shift+F7 does works, you can switch between Design View & XAML using Shift+F7 in your Visual Studio 2013 Update 2.

Comment: well on Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 here, F7 takes me right to the code behind, and it is not mentioned in the ContextMenu, like in your case.

Comment: and what about Shift+F7?

Comment: Shift+F7 doesn't work at all, they aren't even listed as it's on the ContextMenu in your case.

Comment: I just checked in a Visual Studio 2013 Update 2, they have the same ContextMenu as in Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 RC. Also same menu in WPF as well as Windows Phone too. And it works too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57729/discussion-between-aymendaoudi-and-vyas-27).

Comment: @Vyas_27 You don't need VS2013 update 3 to solve this. You can achieve that even in VS2012 express for WP. Shift+f7 switches only to XAML and not to design as Aymen mentioned in the question. I don't know how this answer is accepted.

Comment: @BalasubramaniM I know you don't need visual studio 2013 update 3 rc, there was problem assigning the shortcut key Shift+F7, which got cleared http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57729/discussion-between-aymendaoudi-and-vyas-27. That is the reason why this answer got accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Shift+F7 did not work for me while in split view, but it did once I hit collapse and was only looking at one view. It doesn't matter if its source(xaml) or design as long as it's not split.

You can change each file to be collapsed and visual studio will remember. You can change the default mode a .xaml file will open in by going to tools-->options-->k XAML Designer--> change selected item in combobox labeled Default Document View from Split View to Source View. Will only work for files it's not remembering your last view for which is probably everything you're working on.

You could wipe out the .suo file if you really want the default to take effect for anything other than the things you've never touched ever. That's what I did.